# Problema con expresión regular en php

Tags: php

Ayuda necesito crear una expresión regular que me valide unas medidas que comiencen con el siguiente patrón:

> 23'-

Lo que este después del **`-`** no importa ya que puede ser que también tenga medidas similares o enteros con fracciones como **1 2/3**, estuve intentado realizarla pero al momento de imprimir el resultado no me da lo esperado ya que en es una tabla que también contiene otros campos con el patrón similar solo que no comienzan así por ejemplo **`3/4 x 0'-2 3/4`**, no tengo mucho conocimiento del tema por lo que no estoy seguro si lo que estuve haciendo es correcto.

```
$patron="/^[\w]+[\d'-]/";
```

Ejemplos de pruebas de patrones:

> `17'- 1 7/8` **correcto**
> `0'-10 15/16` **correcto**
> `0'-9` **correcto**
> `1/2 x 0'-2` **incorrecto**
> `3/4 x 0'-2` **incorrecto**

Comment: No entiendo bien el patón ¿podrías poner ejemplos de valores válidos donde queda claro el patrón?

Comment: Una disculpa ya agregue unos ejemplos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este patrón pasa con todos los ejemplos que has puesto

`$patron="/^[0-9]+'-.*$/";`

Cadenas que empiezan con un número de al menos un dígito seguidos de **'-** y que después puedan o no contener cualquier otra cosa (nada, letras, otras medidas, etc).

Espero que te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias amigo me sirvió aunque aun no me queda claro porque lo que esta después del + no va entre corchetes...

Comment: Porque los corchetes sirven para definir "una clase" de caracteres, en este caso, los números del cero al nueve. La expresión se lee algo como: "Una cadena que comience con al menos un dígito entre cero y nueve seguido de un apóstrofe y un guión y que después tenga cualquier combinación de caracteres (incluso ningún caracter)". Espero que esto lo explique mejor.

Comment: Sii ya quedo todo más claro y muchas gracias por la expliciacion amigo